# Get element inside element by ID and class - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Alright, I've dabbled in JavaScript before, but the most useful thing I've written is a CSS style-switcher. So I'm somewhat new to this. Let's say I have HTML code like this:

```
<div class="first">
    <div id="bar">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

Not Working:document.getElementsByClassName("first").getElementById("bar")[0];

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, not a object for further querying

Comment: Despite the fact you should not use an id if you habe multiple of them, as Napoli stated getElementsByClassName returns a collection of nodes, which can't be queried further. Use document.querySelector('.first #bar') in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

With that you can use CSS selectors and do e.g.

```
var bar_element = document.querySelector(".first #bar");
```